# How to set Firebase Custom DocID using Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter/Dart in my app, I can register users with de next sentence

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').add(toMap(user));
```

but Firebase, creates the document with an automatic id, I want to create the document with the username to perfom the queries based on the username. (Find the products using the username)

[image]

I tried set the id in the User DTO but Firebase save it with automatic id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the user's id to create the document like this

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData(toMap(user));
```

Comment: great! setData returns Future<void> then, how can I check the successful request to Firebase to take a decission based on that?

Comment: await the setData, if something goes wrong an error will be thrown but if successful there will be no errors.